# How to grab the filestamp in a nice format?

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

gurus in the Net.
I am having issues trying to output a nice looking format of this batch file :

---

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (c:\temp\machine_list.txt) do (
    echo %%G
    echo %%G >> c:\temp\Log.txt
    dir "\\%%G\C$\Logs\filelog.txt" /A >> c:\temp\Log.txt
    )
```

---

This batch works, but it is just fast and dirty:
For each machine a lot of useless information are printed :

---

```
Machine_id
 Volume in drive \\Machine_001\C$\Logs is System
 Volume Serial Number is 0271-2533

 Directory of \\Machine_001\C$\Logs

14.03.2018  11:33             7'722 filelog.txt
               1 File(s)          7'722 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  347'223'621'632 bytes free
```

---

My question is :

there is a way to have a nice log ?
.i.e :

```
Machine_id1    14.03.2018  11:33             7'722 filelog.txt
Machine_id2    14.03.2018  11:33             7'722 filelog.txt
Machine_id3    14.03.2018  11:33             7'722 filelog.txt
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch script should work as you intended it to:

```bat
@(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt"
) Do @For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In ('Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"'
) Do @Echo %%A    %%B)>"C:\temp\Log.txt"
```

I won't explain how it all works, but the important part is the nested `For` loop. It runs the `Dir` command as intended, but ignores all lines beginning with the character <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. This is done by setting the end of line, `EOL` to that character, using a rather odd looking but effective syntax.

**Edit**

Perhaps this will achieve the aims of your latest comments:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt") Do (
    If Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\" (
        For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In ('Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"') Do >>"C:\temp\Log.txt"  Echo %%A    %%B
    ) Else >>"C:\temp\Log_error.txt" Echo %%A)
```

**Edit 2**

This is a futher modified example for hopefully better logging of errors:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt") Do (
    If Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt" (
        (For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In (
            'Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"'
        ) Do Echo %%A %%B)>>"C:\temp\Log.txt") Else ((
            If Not Exist "\\%%A\C$\" Echo %%A    inaccessible
            Echo %%A    missing filelog.txt)>>"C:\temp\ErrLog.txt"))
```

Comment: As I told, It works fine.
Now I am facing how to manage the error texts that now are just printed in the cmd shell :

The system cannot find the file specified.
The network path was not found.
Access is denied.
The target account name is incorrect.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: An `If Exist` statement may help: `@(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt") Do @If Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\" For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In ('Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"') Do @Echo %%A    %%B)>"C:\temp\Log.txt"`.

Comment: If I well decrypt ( :-) ) your script, you are managing only the machines in which the script is able to search. If in the same time I would like to manage the error, I should add something like 
Do "at"if NOT Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\" "at"Echo %%A>"C:\temp\Log_error.txt" 
Is it correct? thanks

Comment: @Romeo, I've added an Edit section to my answer as further help.

Comment: I am too stupid for batch... :-(.

@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt") Do (
    If Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\" (
        For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In ('Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"') Do >>"C:\temp\Log.txt"  Echo %%A    %%B
    ) Else (
 echo %%A>"c:\temp\tmpmachine.txt"
 set /p machine=<"c:\temp\tmpmachine.txt"
 echo machine %machine%
 dir /a "\\%%A\C$\Logs\">"c:\temp\tmperror.txt" 2>&1
 set /p error=<"c:\temp\tmperror.txt"
 echo error %error%
 echo %machine%  %error%>>"C:\temp\Log_error.txt" 
 )
 )

Comment: As  you can see I have done the same thing to print out a file in the format :
Machine    Error
but the variable set from the file are empty.

Comment: @Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\temp\machine_list.txt") Do (
    If Exist "\\%%A\C$\Logs\" (
        For /F EOL^=^ ^ Delims^= %%B In ('Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt"') Do >>"C:\temp\Log.txt"  Echo %%A    %%B
    ) Else (
 Echo %%A >>"C:\temp\Log_error.txt"  
 Dir /A "\\%%A\C$\Logs\filelog.txt" >>"C:\temp\Log_error.txt" 2>&1
)
)

This is the second tentative, the output works, but not on the same line.

Comment: @Romeo, I've provided yet another edit, **Edit 2**. Please note that my initial answer does not come with unlimited future support. Please consider posting a new question should the task continue to be modified post acceptance.

Comment: many thanks for the "quite-infinite" support. your edit 2 was fine. In the case, I will create a new question. many thanks again